# How to set custom HTML id attribute for the :check_boxes of a SimpleForm association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, simple-form

Let's say that I have the following code:

```rb
form.association :users, as: :check_boxes, collection: User.all, label: 'Users'
```

where `form` is a [SimpleForm](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) builder. This generates:

```html
<div class="input check_boxes optional some_model_users">
  <label class="check_boxes optional">Users</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="some_model[user_ids][]" value="" autocomplete="off">

  <span class="checkbox">
    <label for="some_model_user_ids_1">
      <input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="some_model[user_ids][]" id="some_model_user_ids_1">
      Bruce Wayne
    </label>
  </span>

    <span class="checkbox">
      <label for="some_model_user_ids_2">
        <input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="2" name="some_model[user_ids][]" id="some_model_user_ids_2">
        Clark Kent
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

But, I want to set a custom HTML `id` attribute for the individual `input[type=checkbox]` elements. Is there any way to do this via SimpleForm?

### For more context

[image]

Basically, we have `select` input field called as "Type". When the type is "Users", the checkbox collection label should say "Users". But, when the type is "Blogs", then the checkbox collection label should say "Authors". However, the `name` attribute of the checkboxes in both the collections should still be based on the `User` model. But this creates a problem such that the checkbox labels from the second collection gets associated with the checkboxes from the first collection. This is because the `id` attribute is duplicated, so we need a way to make it custom.

Comment: Can you advise why you need to add a specific `id` to each element? You would have to do this long hand via a loop but maybe there is an easier way to achieve your goal if you describe what that is.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have updated the description. Please check.